# Getting related data in .Net Core 3.1

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, linq, .net-core, ef-code-first

I am trying to get related data from 2 tables. I am using .NET Core 3.1, EF Core, and the code-first approach. What I want is to pass a `customerid` (which is a foreign key in the `order` table) to get all the orders of that customer. I get some related output but I don't know how to get specific output.

I have commented out the `.ThenInclude` because it causes an error:

> Lambda expression is not valid

`Customer` model class:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace CRUDRelationship.Models
{
    public class Customer
    {
        [Key]
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        //public List<Order> Order { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`Order` model class:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace CRUDRelationship.Models
{
    public class Order
    {
        [Key]
        public int OrderId { get; set; }
        public  int Total { get; set; }
        
        [ForeignKey("Customer")]
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public Customer customer { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Interface:

```
using CRUDRelationship.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CRUDRelationship.Data
{
    public interface ICustomerData
    {
        List<Customer> GetCustomers();
        Customer GetCustomer(int id);
        Customer AddCustomer(Customer customer);
        List<Order> GetOrderByCustomer(int CustomerId);
        Order AddOrder(Order order);
    }
}
```

Implementation:

```
using CRUDRelationship.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CRUDRelationship.Data
{
    public class CustomerData : ICustomerData
    {
        private InvetoryContext _invetoryContext;

        public CustomerData(InvetoryContext invetoryContext)
        {
            _invetoryContext = invetoryContext;
        }

        public Customer AddCustomer(Customer customer)
        {
            _invetoryContext.Customers.Add(customer);
            _invetoryContext.SaveChanges();
            return customer;
        }

        public Order AddOrder(Order order)
        {
            _invetoryContext.Orders.Add(order);
            _invetoryContext.SaveChanges();
            return order;
        }

        public Customer GetCustomer(int id)
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }

        public List<Customer> GetCustomers()
        {
            return _invetoryContext.Customers.ToList();
        }

        public List<Order> GetOrderByCustomer(int CustomerId)
        {
            return  _invetoryContext.Orders
           .Include(order => order.customer)
           //.ThenInclude(customer => customer.Name)
           .Where(order => order.CustomerId == CustomerId).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

`Customer` table:

[image]

`Order` table:

[image]

Output I get when I pass customer id 2:

```
[
    {
        "orderId": 2,
        "total": 200,
        "customerId": 2,
        "customer": {
            "customerId": 2,
            "name": "Ankit",
            "email": "ankit@gmail.com"
        }
    },
    {
        "orderId": 4,
        "total": 15000,
        "customerId": 2,
        "customer": {
            "customerId": 2,
            "name": "Ankit",
            "email": "ankit@gmail.com"
        }
    }
]
```

This is the output I want:

```
{
  "customer": {
    "customerId": 2,
    "name": "Ankit",
    "email": "ankit@gmail.com",
    "Order": [
      {
        "orderId": 2,
        "total": 200,
        "customerId": 2
      },
      {
        "orderId": 4,
        "total": 15000,
        "customerId": 2
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: **Typo** alert - it should be **inventory** - not "invetory" - as in your `InvetoryContext` ....

Comment: Did you run your migration with `public List<Order> Order { get; set; }` or without it, I see you have commented the property?

Comment: using CRUDRelationship.Models.ViewModel;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace CRUDRelationship.Models

{
    public class InventoryContext : DbContext
    {
        public InventoryContext(DbContextOptions<InventoryContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }
        public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    }
}
  My Inventory Context class. Migrations are working fine